# Truncate Decimal value till 2 points using Data Annotations

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a decimal property in my model to show some amount figure

When i check my API in swagger of any JSON editor tools than it shows #.00 format (two digit after decimal points), but when I hit it into browser than it shows #.0000 format (4 digit after decimal points).

Can someone explain what is this behavior and what is the solution for this

as I tried regex for this but seems like it is for validation only , does not take any action for truncating its value till 2 digit

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$")]
```

Example : Expected value is 67.50 instead of 67.500 using data annotation (preferred way) instead of using ToString("F2") or ToString("#.00")

Edit 1 :

A more detailed example:

property value is 67.5000 when we hit api in browser ,

Property value is 67.50 when check through swagger or postman tools

consuming api in many apps (MVC, Angular 6, android) and getting 67.5000 when display on web page.

Can be solved using string formatter but front end is not accessible to me , only solution is to correct this in api level (minimum code change is desired so preferred data annotation combination)

Comment: Can you flesh out your example a little bit more, please? I expect this has to do with needing to format the value for display, rather than validating the input.

Comment: @Llama you correct , format instead of validate , api consumer should get #.00 format , I have update my question with an more detailed example

Comment: If the JSON response contains 67.50 then there's nothing you can do because you've already done all that you can. The clients aren't wrong for interpreting 67.50 as 67.5000 since they're both representations of the same value, but if something different is required then the client must be modified.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem recently.

You can create a new class and override the default json behavior of your serializer.

Beware the solution is for .net core 2.1. It will also work for .NET 5 with changes to startup class code.

**Create a file and name it anything like DecimalPrecisionUtil.cs and add the following code to it.**

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace YourNamespace {
  public class DecimalPrecsionUtil: JsonConverter < decimal > {

    public override decimal ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, decimal existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
      return Convert.ToDecimal(reader.Value);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, decimal value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
      writer.WriteValue(string.Format("{0:F2}", value));
    }
  }
}
```

**Add the following code in startup.cs file (the code is for .net core 2.1 and you might need to change this a bit for .NET 5**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            //adding overriden json serializer options
            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new DecimalPrecsionUtil());
            });
        }
```

In case you just need to Show two decimal precision when returning data from api but need to retain full precision when data is sent to the api, you can modify the **ReadJson** method in **DecimalPrecisionUtil** and instead of returning the decimal value, just throw a **NotImplementedException**.